# Can't see Dialogflow access tokens

Tags: chat, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, api-ai

I'm not using the enterprise edition Dialogflow but I still can't see the developer and client access tokens.
I'm creating my own custom integration and I have been using the client access token that I could see in the General settings. Now both the client and developer access tokens aren't there.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow v2 no longer uses developer/client access tokens. Those were for v1 only.

You need to [setup authentication](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/setup#auth) and download private keys now to access the API endpoints.